# Windows 10 does not wake on schedule

Tags: windows-10, sleep, scheduled-tasks

I recently upgraded a Win7 media server to Windows 10 pro.  I have a scheduled task to wake the server at a specified time; however it no longer works in Windows 10.  It worked perfectly fine in 7.  Now, it only works if the computer has been sleeping for less than about one hour.

I have tried changing the following power options:

- Disabling hibernation
- Turn off hard disk after: never
- Allowed wake timers
- Changing system sleep state in BIOS

Noting has worked.  The scheduled wake up is just ignored.  Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing power options.

---

- Right-click on power options (In the taskbar).
- Change plan settings (whatever plan you are using, either balanced or power saving, or high performance).
- Change advanced power settings.
- check the power setting in the drop-down box.
- Scroll down till you see **sleep** menu.
- expand it.
- Expand **Allow wake timers**.
- change it from "Important wake Timers only/disable" to "***Enable***"